# What is the underlying mechanism of Prolog's operation?

Tags: prolog

I have the above code, and I'm not sure which of the two has_divisor clauses will be called when has_divisor is invoked. Can someone explain this to me?

```
is_prime(2).
is_prime(3).
is_prime(P):-
    P>3,
    integer(P),
    P mod 2 =\= 0,
    \+ has_divisor(P,3).

has_divisor(N,D):-
    N mod D =:= 0.
has_divisor(N, D):-
    D * D < N,
    D2 is D + 2,
    has_divisor(N, D2).
```

Comment: One of these might help https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=explain+prolog

Answer (score 0):

> What is the underlying mechanism of Prolog's operation?

You can read about it in a book here: https://www.let.rug.nl/bos/lpn/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlch2 chapter 2 "unification and proof search". It searches the code top down, looking for predicates with the same name ('functor') and same number of arguments (same 'arity') and where the arguments can be 'unified' (a kind of structural pattern matching), and then tries all of them in order they appear in the file until it's found an answer or a failure or checked all the code.

> which of the two has_divisor clauses will be called when has_divisor is invoked

As many as are necessary to either prove or disprove the query. If P is divisible by 3, only the first one is necessary so only the first one will be called, and then is_prime fails. If P is not divisible by three, the first one will be tried, then second one will be tried and that calls the first one again, and maybe that calls the second one again...